# Add tap events to elements inside an SVG using SkiaSharp in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to get the particular points inside the svg for xamarin.forms
Is there is any ways from which I can achieve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add touch events to particular points using Skiasharp. You just have to filter actions by Locations. Assuming you are using Xaml and C#, you Xaml code would look like this

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="White"
        Grid.Row="1">

    <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                        PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
    <Grid.Effects>
        <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                        TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
    </Grid.Effects>
</Grid>
```

and then your C# would be like this

```
void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
{
    // Convert Xamarin.Forms point to pixels
    Point pt = args.Location;
    SKPoint point = 
        new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                    (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));

    // Uncomment the code below based on what you specifically need
    // if (point != The Point you care about) or (pt != The Location you care about
        // return;
    switch (args.Type)
    {
        case TouchActionType.Pressed:
            if (bitmap.HitTest(point))
            {
                touchIds.Add(args.Id);
                bitmap.ProcessTouchEvent(args.Id, args.Type, point);
                break;
            }
            break;

        case TouchActionType.Moved:
            if (touchIds.Contains(args.Id))
            {
                bitmap.ProcessTouchEvent(args.Id, args.Type, point);
                canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
            }
            break;

        case TouchActionType.Released:
        case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
            if (touchIds.Contains(args.Id))
            {
                bitmap.ProcessTouchEvent(args.Id, args.Type, point);
                touchIds.Remove(args.Id);
                canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Charles Petzold authored [these Github examples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/16fc63e484439b800964fcb9ed84ff0feda1634b/SkiaSharpForms/Demos/Demos/SkiaSharpFormsDemos/Transforms) with Skiasharp, check them out to get a better idea

Comment: thanks for the help but it always calling when I tap I want to work tap on some specific location.

Comment: @AditKothari I thought you would be able to figure it out after what I shared so I didn't add that specific part. You have to take my code and create a conditional as shown in the commented code, with the variable- "point" or "pt". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Answering this old question to maybe help future explorers like myself - in my app I went with SkiaSharp's own tap handlers that are on `SKCanvas`. You turn them on with the `EnableTouchEvents` property and then set the callback in the `Touch` property. Also, in the callback handler make sure to set `e.Handled = true;` on the `SKTouchEventArgs` or else you won't get the full spectrum of `SKTouchAction` types. Tap location is also included.