# Xamarin Microcharts: Is it possible to show tooltip on microchart

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp, skia

Is it possible to display a tooltip on click on the bars in Microchart? This feature is available in [syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/tooltip).

I am trying to see if the bars can accept touch events and display a popup on click. I don't see any relevant documentation but trying it by using SKCanvasView as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836083/add-tap-events-to-elements-inside-an-svg-using-skiasharp-in-xamarin-forms), but haveen't found any problem solution yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I see no mention of that in the repo, so I'd guess the short answer is "no".  However, it's open source so you can always add a feature yourself and submit it as a PR.

Comment: any idea how to approach it? How I can do it?

Comment: No, I've never looked at their source.  You could post in their repo requesting some pointers to get started.

Comment: @Jason https://github.com/microcharts-dotnet/Microcharts